Make clickable row in React Data Table call component that redirects to new page in NextJS
I'm using NextJS 15.0. I have a React Data Table Component (version 7.6.2) and I've made the rows clickable. When a user clicks a row, it calls a function called onHandleClick. Here is the code...
<DataTable
  onRowClicked={onHandleClick}
/>

Here is what the onHandleClick function looks like...
const onHandleClick = (row:any) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  router.push("/");
}

I want two things to happen:
FIRST, I want to redirect the user (after they click the row) to a new page or I want a new component to load...
and
SECOND, I want the data (the parameter row in the onHandleClick function) to pass over to the new page/component so that I can populate the page/component with that data to be displayed to the user.
I tried the code above and I'm getting an Invalid Hook Call error in the browser. It's not redirecting me when I click on any row in the Data table.
Here's what I did to try to fix this issue:
I tried using UseEffect() inside the function call.
I tried using onClick as a parameter inside the  component.
These efforts did not fix the issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!
